# R: Reading a file with different parts separated by #

Tags: r, import

I have a txt file structured like that (this is an extract of the file):

```
# A network in a general multiplex format
*Vertices 280
1 "S1MRS0008.MID02.02.P2.nov13"
2 "S1MRS0038.MID11.11.P2.nov13"
3 "S1MRS0060.MID18.18.P2.nov13"
4 "S1MRS0070.MID19.19.P2.nov13"
*Multiplex
# layer node layer node [weight]
# Intralayer edges
1 49 1 80 0.0930232558139535
1 40 1 39 0.0652173913043478
1 40 1 72 0.0652173913043478
1 40 1 67 0.0652173913043478
# Interlayer edges
1 30 2 122 0.0652173913043478
1 61 2 148 0.0681818181818182
1 37 2 164 0.108695652173913
1 5 2 164 0.06
```

Using R, I would like to read the `Intralayer` and `Interlayer` parts and create a data frame (with 5 columns) of each. I would prefer to do that without manually breaking the file in parts because I have many of them. Any ideas?

Comment: So what's the desired output here? With a file this irregular, you're probably going to have to read it all in using `readLines()` and then parse out the parts you want by using `grep()` to find the lines of interest.

Comment: If it's always the same format (network, intralayer and interlayer chunks in that order) - first get row number using `reaLines()` and regular expressions (if needed). Then read only that part of the file by specifying `skip`, `sep` and `dec` parameters in, say, `data.table::fread()`

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was a way around `readLines`, but apparently not. These suggested solutions work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Read the data into `L` from a file (see commented out line) or character string. 
 Next form a grouping variable `g` which distinguishes the parts.  Split that into a list of parts, `s` and then remove the first line of each part giving `Content`.  `has_len[i]` is TRUE if there are nonzero number of lines in the ith part of `Content`.  Now read the lines in those components of `Content` having lines and set the names from the first line of each component of `s`.  No packages are used.

```
# L <- trimws(readLines("myfile"))
L <- trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines)))

g <- cumsum(grepl("^[#*]", L))
s <- split(L, g)

Content <- lapply(s, tail, -1)
has_len <- lengths(Content) > 0
Content <- lapply(Content[has_len], function(x) read.table(text = x))
names(Content) <- sub("^[#*] ", "", sapply(s, head, 1))[has_len]
```

giving:

```
> Content

$`*Vertices 280`
  V1                          V2
1  1 S1MRS0008.MID02.02.P2.nov13
2  2 S1MRS0038.MID11.11.P2.nov13
3  3 S1MRS0060.MID18.18.P2.nov13
4  4 S1MRS0070.MID19.19.P2.nov13

$`Intralayer edges`
  V1 V2 V3 V4         V5
1  1 49  1 80 0.09302326
2  1 40  1 39 0.06521739
3  1 40  1 72 0.06521739
4  1 40  1 67 0.06521739

$`Interlayer edges`
  V1 V2 V3  V4         V5
1  1 30  2 122 0.06521739
2  1 61  2 148 0.06818182
3  1 37  2 164 0.10869565
4  1  5  2 164 0.06000000
```

### Note

Above we used this for Lines:

```
Lines <- '# A network in a general multiplex format
*Vertices 280
1 "S1MRS0008.MID02.02.P2.nov13"
2 "S1MRS0038.MID11.11.P2.nov13"
3 "S1MRS0060.MID18.18.P2.nov13"
4 "S1MRS0070.MID19.19.P2.nov13"
*Multiplex
# layer node layer node [weight]
# Intralayer edges
1 49 1 80 0.0930232558139535
1 40 1 39 0.0652173913043478
1 40 1 72 0.0652173913043478
1 40 1 67 0.0652173913043478
# Interlayer edges
1 30 2 122 0.0652173913043478
1 61 2 148 0.0681818181818182
1 37 2 164 0.108695652173913
1 5 2 164 0.06'
```